# create joins with a null value

Tags: mysql

I have a table "products" and a table "orders"
the Orders table has the following fields: "id_products" and "id_users"
to join the two tables then write:

```
SELECT * FROM products as p LEFT JOIN orders as o ON p.id_products=o.id_products
```

I would like to create a JOIN with all the products you have ordered the user with id 1 and products that still have to order.

Edit:

```
SELECT * FROM products LEFT JOIN orders 
ON products.id_products= orders.id_products
WHERE user_id = 1 OR user_id IS NULL
```

Comment: **Column Name** of that NULL Value Column ??

Comment: You may want to read more about [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM products LEFT JOIN orders 
ON products.id_products= orders.id_products
Where user.id = 1
```

Comment: This query shows me all the products ordered by the user with id 1, but excludes products that has yet to order (which would have NULL value)

Comment: WHERE user.id = 1 AND ColumnName != NULL

Answer (score 0):

Does not

```
SELECT * FROM products as p LEFT OUTER JOIN orders as o ON p.id_products=o.id_products  
where id_users = 1
```

do what you want?

Comment: This query shows me all the products ordered by the user with id 1, but excludes products that has yet to order (which would have NULL value)

Comment: stupid me, retype to a left outer join (edite answer). That should give you all products with order information where appicaple.